# nginx proxy_pass to dynamic url

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have multiple backend servers and I want to proxy all servers using a single nginx server instance. I don't want to change nginx.conf whenever I add a new backend server.

For example: Server 1 : 192.168.10.1:8080, Server2: 192.168.10.2:8080, etc
Nginx is running on [example.com](http://example.com). I want to access Server1 by using [example.com?ip=192.168.10.1](http://example.com?ip=192.168.10.1), [example.com?ip=192.168.10.2](http://example.com?ip=192.168.10.2) etc

I tried this configuration, but it is giving 500 error page.

```
location / {
   proxy_pass http://$arg_ip:8080;
   proxy_set_header Host      $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

Is there something I am missing? Is there any other way of achieving this?

Comment: You changed the config file but you don't want to change the config file?

Comment: @Rob, Updated my question, I mean to say I don't want to change it whenever I add a new instance

Comment: Please post an error log fragment related to the error.

Answer (score 4):

```
server {
    server_name dynamic_host;
    listern 8080;

    #resolver 8.8.8.8;
    #seems you don't need resolver because you use ip address

    location / {
        if ( $arg_address != "" ) {
            proxy_pass $arg_address;

            #proxy_pass $arg_address$uri
            #proxy_pass $arg_address$request_uri
        }

    }
}
```

the difference between the three proxy_pass

1. $proxy_address
   `example.com?address=http://192.168.10.2:8080/`  goes to
   `http://192.168.10.2:8080/`
2. $proxy_address$uri
   `example.com/test/path?address=http://192.168.10.2:8080/`  goes to
   `http://192.168.10.2:8080/test/path`
3. $proxy_address$request_uri
   `example.com/test/path?address=http://192.168.10.2:8080/&param=value`  goes to
   `http://192.168.10.2:8080/test/path?address=http://192.168.10.2:8080/&param=value`

you can change the param `address` to `ip`, in this case, don't forget to change `$arg_address` to `$arg_ip`.
reference:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables